# ReactJS VSCode Debugging

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I can not for the life of me figure out how to set a breakpoint in a vsx file in the following SPA template: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/templates/ReactReduxSpa

I tried Visual Studio 2017, and now I am trying it in VSCode. Both say the Symbols are not loaded when I try to set a breakpoint in any of the vsx files, or the tsx files.  Why is this? Perhaps its my ignorance on how all of this works but I don't get it!